# osx shell terminates after using 

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell-script

I have a shell script that changes directory and then runs. I want the directory change to be bubbled to the command prompt once the script terminates.

So, I run it with:

```
. script
```

However, now when the script terminates, the whole window terminates. Is there a way to fix this?

My shell is bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to remedy this in Mac

A> Go to your Preferences for Terminal, Select [General], and uncheck the box that says "Close window if shell exits cleanly".

B> Point your favourite text editor to
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Find the rows:

```
 < key>ShellExitAction< /key>
< integer>1< /integer>
```

change the 1 to a 2 and restart the terminal app..

B is basically the same as A, but done manually.

Comment: Also, you'll want to save the change in your standard Terminal profile, so it persists across new instances.

Answer (score 5):

Does `script` contain an `exit` statement? Remember that dot (sourcing) runs your code in the current shell.  So if it has an `exit`, your current shell exits.  You may want to check script and change any `exit` to `return`.

You may be able to detect being sourced (where you'd want to do `return`) and being run (where you may want `exit`)

```
[[ $BASH_SOURCE != $0 ]] && echo 'running sourced ...'
```

Comment: For shells that don't have `$BASH_SOURCE`, you can use `$_` but you have to save it as the first thing in the script since the execution of each command overwrites it.